# long delay launching game on real device

Tags: ios, initialization, sprite-kit, delay

Nearing the end of my first (very simple) game using spritekit.
I have noted a long delay (about 10 -13 seconds) when running the app on a real device at start up.
I am assuming this is the time taken to load resources and execute code in initWithSize().

Is there a workaround or what is the recommend approach i.e. use a splash screen while game loads.
I am using a texture atlas but my understanding is that is for optimising resource calls during runtime.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the instruments tool can help you locate where bottlenecks appear in code. I doubt it is 10-13 seconds from app launch as any app that takes 10 seconds or longer to launch is killed by the system.

Try to load resources intelligently. Load what is absolutely necessary when launching for what I assume would be your menu. If there are variations in different gameplay roles or similar assets used across multiple levels. Load them up, then when a selection has been made load anymore initial resources.

Also try to recycle resources where possible. For instance if an enemy is destroyed by the player. Don't destroy the object. Reuse it, the memory space it took up is likely to be the same again and creation is more expensive than reusing.

I found a lot of brilliant pointers in using Profiling tools through the WWDC talks, they are always a great resource.

Comment: Thanks for the  adivce, I will look into what's going in initWithSize and see what's slowling things down. All sprites are removed from memory when destroyed, how would  go about reusing?

Comment: Remove them from the scene, but keep an array of "killed enemies" before creating a new one, see if there is one available, get it, reset the position and behaviour and add back into the scene. Of course taking it off the array

Comment: Ok a pool of killed enemies got it, great resource of videos  by the way didn't know that existed

Comment: They're brilliant, going to the talks is brilliant to talk to the engineers, but having the videos on hand for reference whenever is also brilliant.

Comment: Watched the tut on spritekite, what one did u watch that was Good for profiling etc

Comment: One on Instruments I believe it was